# phonegap cordova native android menubutton not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, menu

I'm having trouble firing the native menu button on Android through Cordova phonegap version 4.0.0. I have also implemented the back button and it's working fine. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong here. Seems ok according to the cordova docs. This fails when running tests on a Samsung S4.

```
init : function () {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady : function() {
// Register the event listener
document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener('menubutton', this.onMenuKeyDown, false);
},

onMenuKeyDown : function(event) {
alert('menu phone home');
}
```

And the init function is invoked after load, and as I mentioned onBackKeyDown works. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a bug, I'm also experiencing it, have you found a solution?

Comment: This is a known issue with cordova. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8921

Answer (score 3):

This was supposedly fixed, but still requires an undocumented line.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    ...
    navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);  // <-- Add this line
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
    ...
}, false);
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9949#comment-14989073